# ggplot2: change the order of bars so that bars with smaller values are on top of bars with larger values

Tags: r, ggplot2

Here is a sample of my data and graph:

```
m <- c("jun","jun","jul","aug","aug")
a <- c(1,10,2,10,2)
b <- c("x","y","x","x","y")

df <- data.frame(m,a,b)

ggplot(df,
       aes(x=m, y=a, fill=b)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity")
```

[image]

I would like the x value of one to show up on the jun bar. I *want* the bars to be on top of one another not side by side.

*I ended up using transparency. But I am still curious if their is another way to do it.*

Comment: Why don't you want to use `position = "dodge"`?

Comment: remove position = "identity" and x value of 1 will be shown on Jun bar

Answer (score 1):

What I'd do:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = m, y = a, fill = b)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_dodge(preserve = "single"))
```

[image]

Make sure you have the latest version of **ggplot2**: `devtools::install_github("tidyverse/ggplot2")`.

Answer (score 0):

Using transparency gets what I want:

```
ggplot(df,
       aes(x=m, y=a, fill=b)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", position = "identity", alpha=0.5)
```